# Xcode sort init and release

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

It is C++ code in cocos2d-x.

```
Hoge::Hoge()
        : c(NULL),
          b(NULL),
          a(NULL){}

Hoge::~Hoge() {
        CC_SAFE_RELEASE(c);
        CC_SAFE_RELEASE(b);
        CC_SAFE_RELEASE(a)
```

I'd like to sort variable.

```
Hoge::Hoge()
    : a(NULL),
      b(NULL),
      c(NULL){}

Hoge::~Hoge() {
    CC_SAFE_RELEASE(a);
    CC_SAFE_RELEASE(b);
    CC_SAFE_RELEASE(c);
```

do you know the plugin name in Xcode?

Comment: It is interesting that your initialization and release orders are the same. Typically one would expect them to be opposite, to allow for dependencies between `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: yes. I mistook to copy and paste.. I fix.